# background worker with windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm creating a windows service in Visual Studio 2010 with C# and I have few methods like `Add`, `Multiply` and others, which I'm putting in the `onStart` method. Now, I want these methods to run after every five minutes. So how would a background worker process help me in this?

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    add(); // yes, it doesn't have parameters      
}
```

Comment: I think a `System.Timers.Timer` is likely to be more helpful. A background worker is useful for doing work in another thread without blocking the current one (like the UI thread).

Comment: okay thanks, let me go ahead with timers then

Comment: Probably, you may want to refer this - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80997/multi-threading-in-c-net-windows-service

Comment: If you are going to need exact precision (e.g. The method should execute exactly after n minutes), try Quartz.NET: http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=quartz%20.net&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fquartznet.sourceforge.net%2F&ei=E5baUO2xEYXCswahyoDQCQ&usg=AFQjCNHrBIKKhhAn1j5TIyC4rEO_1IuaAA&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.Yms

Comment: @vcsjones: I believe piyush is going to do this in a Windows service, so he may want to use System.Threading.Timer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The timer is the right way to go. I have a slightly enhanced version that takes care of the shutdown of the timer in the OnStop method.

in your program.cs, I would do the following to make debugging easier:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace SampleWinSvc
{
  static class Program
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
#if (!DEBUG)
      ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
      ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new Service1() };
      ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#else
      //Debug code: this allows the process to run 
      // as a non-service. It will kick off the
      // service start point, and then run the 
      // sleep loop below.
      Service1 service = new Service1();
      service.Start();
      // Break execution and set done to true to run Stop()
      bool done = false;
      while (!done)
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
      service.Stop();
#endif
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in your Service1.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Timers;
using System.Text;

namespace SampleWinSvc
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This timer willl run the process at the interval specified (currently 10 seconds) once enabled
        /// </summary>
        Timer timer = new Timer(10000);

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Start();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            // point the timer elapsed to the handler
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            // turn on the timer
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the service is being stopped. 
            /// You need to wrap up pretty quickly or ask for an extension.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;
        }

            /// <summary>
            /// Runs each time the timer has elapsed. 
            /// Remember that if the OnStop turns off the timer, 
            /// that does not guarantee that your process has completed. 
            /// If the process is long and iterative, 
            /// you may want to add in a check inside it 
            /// to see if timer.Enabled has been set to false, or 
            /// provide some other way to check so that 
            /// the process will stop what it is doing.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sender"></param>
            /// <param name="e"></param>
        void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyFunction();
        }

        private int secondsElapsed = 0;
        void MyFunction()
        {
            secondsElapsed += 10;
        }
    }
}
```

By setting the #DEBUG var in your compile options you allow yourself to run the code
as a program and then when you are ready to test your shutdown logic, simply break all and 
set done to true. I have been using this method for years with much success.

As commented in the code, if you are doing anything lengthy in your timer event, then you may want to monitor it from the OnStop to make sure it has enough time if shutdown in the middle of things.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap  up these function in a class and create a System.Timers.Timer() in that class and call all these function in that timer. Call the Start() function  of the sample class NewClass on `OnStart` of the service.

```
class NewClass
{
 this._watcherTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
 this._watcherTimer.Interval =  60000;
 this._watcherTimer.Enabled=False;
 this._watcherTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.Timer_Tick);


 public void Start()
{
 this._watcherTimer.Enabled=true;

}


 private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Add();
        Multiply();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution with Backgroundworker:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker bwMyWorker;
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        bwMyWorker = new BackgroundWorker();            
        bwMyWorker.DoWork += delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs workArgs)
        {
            //Endless loop
            for (; ; )
            {
                //Your work... E.g. add()
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)); //Pause for 5 min
            }

        };
        bwMyWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```